# Two definitions of rank one update of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've seen two definitions of rank one update of a matrix:

$$A + xx^t$$
and
$$A + uv^t$$

Are the two forms equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not.
$$A + xx^T$$
is a *symmetric* rank one update, i.e. the matrix $xx^T$ is symmetric, but
$$A + uv^T$$
is not symmetric, i.e. $uv^T$ is not necessarily symmetric.

$uv^T$ can produce any rank one $n \times m$ matrix, whereas $xx^T$ only can produce rank one $n \times n$ symmetric matrices, i.e. $xx^T$ is always square.